# Azure Service Bus "manage claim is required for this operation"

Tags: azure, authentication, azureservicebus

I receive a 401 auth error: "Manage claim is required for this operation" upon executing the following statement:

```
        if (namespaceManager.QueueExists(QueueName))
        {
            namespaceManager.DeleteQueue(QueueName);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old and but wanted to add in my findings since the behavior confused me quite a bit. Hopefully this helps someone looking at this in the future.

You need a Manage claim in order to be able to do TopicExists/QueueExists kind of operations. If the topic or queue doesn't exist you can get away with no exceptions even without a Manage claim which was strange to me.

As of WindowsAzure.ServiceBus v3.4.1.

Comment: Is the same also now on the new Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus v7.1.1 ... totally non sense! I understand the Manage claim for the delete operation, but for the Check operation the Manage claim seems too much for me

Answer (score 3):

After verifying my connection string, I simply Regenerated my primary key for my access policy on the Azure Mgmt. Portal. I used the new key and was able to successfully auth.

Answer (score 3):

Your original key could be generated without `Manage` option, which would result in manage operation failure.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go into the access control (IAM tab) and give your user the following roles:

- Azure Service Bus Data Receiver
- Azure Service Bus Data Sender

[image]